# What is the use of this valve and split in a reverse osmosis water filtration system?

Tags: water, valve

What is the use of this IMG 1: valve and IMG 2: split (splits into the dishwasher) in a reverse osmosis water filtration system?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's called a valve, and without pictures or a diagram that show the complete piping layout, there's no way to tell in isolation what's going on from those two pictures.

Comment: thank you Ecnerwal, why is there a need for the valve in the first picture? I use my water filtration system on a daily basis. I never had the need to close that valve...

Comment: Since you do not show us what it connects to, there is absolutely no way to speculate on its purpose from this side of my computer screen.

Comment: As @Ecnerwal indicated, I/we can't be sure but from RO systems I've worked on that looks like an isolation valve to shut off the water while maintenance is done, such as changing a filter, etc. Can't be sure without more info.